# Non-italic greek letters in matplotlib when using Times New Roman and saving as pdf

Tags: python, pdf, matplotlib

I am trying to generate some plots for a scientific paper with python and matplotlib and the usetex option, following the matplotlib [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/users/usetex.html) for rendering text with LaTeX.

Here's a code example of what I trying.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rc('font',**{'family':'serif','serif':['Palatino']})
plt.rc('text', usetex=True)
plt.plot([-2, 1, 4])
plt.xlabel(r'$\alpha \beta \gamma x y z$')
plt.savefig('plot.pdf')
plt.savefig('plot.png')
plt.show()
```

This will generate everything as expected, but if I change the font to `'Times'`, as I want it to match the text of my paper, the pdf file will have regular greek letters, rather than italic, although they are italic in the png file and when the figure is displayed with the last command. And using the pdf image is preferable because of the better quality.

Why this behaviour? I really need the greek letters to be in italic. Does anyone have any clue on how to achieve that? I have matplotlib 1.4.1, python 2.7.8 on Windows 8.1. My .matplotlib file sets the backend to `TkAgg`. I tried setting `matplotlib.use('PDF')` but the results are the same, except that `plt.show()` does not show anything.

Thanks

Comment: The regular 'Times' font does not contain Greek letters, so presumably Python uses Symbol as a fallback -- and there is no built-in Symbol Italic. Inspect the generated PDF to confirm this, or provide a download link so we can.

Comment: @Jongware I think you are right. Document properties in Adobe Reader tells the fonts used are CMMI10, CMSY10, NimbusRomNo9L-Regu, NimbusRomNo9L-ReguItal and StandardSymL.